# Word for supporter of dictatorship

Tags: single-word-requests

Word for a **supporter**/believer in the cause **of a dictator** (but is not one themselves), or the concept of dictatorship in the general sense.

Dictatorist?  Despotist?

Comment: autocrats? authoritarians?

Comment: @Susan "Autocrat" is the ruler him/herself, not the supporter.

Comment: A "fascist pig"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Despotist** does seem to be a word. From [Merriam-Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despotist)

> despotist: an advocate or supporter of despotism

Another option to consider is **totalitarian**. From [Collins:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/totalitarian)

> totalitarian: a person who advocates or practises totalitarian policies

Comment: Yes Oxford Dictionaries also have it as a noun (which surprised me). Well discovered!

Comment: A dictatorship does not necessarily need to be totalitarian.

Answer (score 4):

**Authoritarian.** From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> A. adj. Favourable to the principle of authority as opposed to that of individual freedom.
>
> 1879 Daily News 28 June 2/6 *Men who are authoritarian by nature, and cannot imagine that a country should be orderly save under a military despotism.*
>   1882 Contemp. Rev. Sept. 459 *Communists of the ‘Authoritarian’ type.*
>
> B. n. One who supports the principle of authority.
>
> 1883 Times 2 Jan. 3/1 *[Gambetta] was accused of being an authoritarian.*
>   1884 Seeley in Encycl. Brit. XVII. 226/1 *A lover of liberty, not an authoritarian.*

Comment: "Authoritarian" is, perhaps, a bit broad.  For example, an authoritarian school teacher would be one who believed in strict classroom discipline, without necessarily saying anything about their political beliefs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes, it covers more than just what Southpaw wants. But it does cover it!

Answer (score 1):

You could also go for *fascist* though, strictly speaking, a dictatorship need not be a *fascist* dictatorship by definition. However, the term *fascist* is used to describe any type of authoritarianism today, even if not linked to the specific political system. See, for example, the 3rd definition below ([source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fascist)):

> fas·cist  [fash-ist]
>
> 1. a person who believes in or sympathizes with fascism.
> 2. ( often initial capital letter ) a member of a fascist movement or party.
>
> **3. a person who is dictatorial or has extreme right-wing views.**